# Netcat HTTP posting

Tags: linux, post, netcat

When using netcat in linux, I can do a get fine from the command line.

```
nc google.com 80
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host:google.com
```

Can someone please show me how to do a post. I tried with no luck. I also tried different combos with \r\n or just a new line. I can get it working in perl and c.

```
nc google.com 80
POST /test.php HTTP/1.1
Host:whatever.com
Content-Type:text/html
Content-Length:10

text=hello
```

The header shows it was successful but nothing gets returned ?
Please help

Comment: Looking at other posts it looks like maybe my \r\t are off. I'm going to run tcpdump and see if they match up

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it working by troubleshooting with wireshark.

I need to add a Content-Type

This works

---

POST /test.php HTTP/1.1
Host:127.0.0.1
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length:9

txt=99999

-----

PHP

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use netcat for a specific reason? 
Curl can send posts natively: http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/311/sending-http-post-using-curl-command/

Comment: netcat is nice just because its on almost all nix box I run :)

Comment: That's what I figured. This might be helpful also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135307/send-post-request-with-netcat