# Sending HTTP request

Tags: http, httprequest

I am trying to upload data from an Arduino to data.sparkfun.com, but somehow it always fails. To make sure that the HTTP request I am sending is correct, I would like to send it from a computer to the server and see if it uploads the correct values.
According to some examples, the request should be formulated like this:

```
GET /input/publicKey?private_key=privateKey&dht1_t=24.23&dht1_h=42.4&dht2_t=24.48&dht2_h=41.5&bmp_t=23.3&bmp_p=984021 HTTP/1.1\n
Host: 54.86.132.254\n
Connection: close\n
\n
```

How do I send this request to the server from my computer? Do I just type in the terminal? Im not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) which should be able to handle your needs.
Even easier and more low level is netcat ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135307/send-post-request-with-netcat) is an example on SO)